# How to export decrypted https traffic from mitm proxy

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, proxy, http-proxy

I am using mitm proxy in order to intercept https traffic to an android device and it seems to work great.  I downloaded and installed the certificate from mitm.it when the android emulator's internet connection is proxied and I can see the unencrypted version of the https traffic in the console, however when I use the -w argument to write the contents of the capture to a file, it shows what seems to be the encrypted version of the text.

What I see from mitm proxy dash

[image]

What the dump file contains.

[image]

So my question is why does the dashboard provide an unencrypted version of the http while the dump of the same session looks to be encrypted?

Comment: It's not encrypted, it's compressed: `Content-Encoding: gzip`. That's why the display says `[decoded gzip] HTML`. This _may_ indicate FB is vulnerable to BREACH (q.v.) although I'm neither willing nor able to go through all their content to analyze it.

Comment: Mitm proxy states that it decodes gzip so I didn't think to check this.  Plus I think you are looking at the top image that is viewable.  Also, even if this was only gzipped and not encrypted, there is no problem with the fb cert, this isn't even technically facebook's cert, it's a proxied cert.  I will post on whether the gzipped version of this does look right though.  Thanks for the help!